# Does ground faucet need to be covered in winter?

Tags: faucet, ground, winter

My house has two exterior faucets that come out of the ground rather than out of the side of the house. I live in North Texas.

When temperatures get significantly below freezing, should these be covered to prevent pipes busting, like you would if they came out of the side of the house?

If so, can anyone recommend an easy and effective method for covering these? I'm unsure how effective an insulator would be if it can't trap residual warmth from the wall of the house.

[image: Spigot coming out of ground]

Comment: Product recommendations are [explicitly off topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), please [edit] to remove that portion. Otherwise, good question.

Comment: Is there a way to drain the line to winterize it? Like, does it go back into the house or is the pipe entirely underground?

Comment: Well or city water? If city water these pipes will be downstream of your meter which means they probably pass through the house foundation/wall. Locate the pass-through  spot in the interior and add a shutoff and bleeder valve.

Comment: How old is your house, or how long have the pipes been this way?

Answer (score 1):

Invert a plant pot (or bucket) over it. Draining would be preferable, but if you can find a styrofoam cup or packing material large enough to cover it, the warmth from the part below ground might still prevent it from freezing, if well enough insulated on top.

A pile of leaves (or straw, or hay, or mulch) OVER the plant pot (or coffee cup/etc. and plant pot) would further insulate it.

Proper fix - replace with a frost-free yard hydrant, which drains below frost line. But that's more work than insulating the thing you have well, at least until it breaks and needs to be replaced anyway. Which might be never in Texas.

Comment: Searching for "rose cone" brings up some styrofoam covers that can be used to help with this.  Though it might be tough to find anything locally in TX like this for covering plants for overnight frost/freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Ecnerwal probably has the most straightforward answer, another option that could work is to build a simple sealed wooden box to cover your faucets down to the ground, and put a low-wattage incandescent lightbulb inside to provide some warmth and keep the inside above freezing temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

Most any lumber or hardware store will have foam rubber sleeves to fit over pipes. Available in a few diameters. Cheap, easy , fast. You have room, so add a bucket with some insulating material for good luck, over the foam sleeve.